# How to run spark sql queries against Hadoop without running a spark job

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I develop spark sql to run against hadoop. Today I must run a spark job that invokes my query. Is there another way to do this? I find I spend too much time fixing side issues with running the jobs in spark. Ideally I want to be able to compose and execute Spark SQL queries directly against hadoop/hbase and bypass the spark job altogether. This would permit much more rapid iteration when debugging or trying alternate queries.

Note that my queries are often 100 lines long or more so working from the command line is challenging.

I have to do this from a WIndows workstation

Comment: Against what source in Hadoop?

Comment: @thebluephantom Spark SQL queries directly against hadoop/hbase

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can use for HBase is to use Apache Phoenix. It provides an SQL interface.

As an example, on my last project I used NIFI with Phoenix to read and mutate HBase data. Worked great from command line. I did discover a bug in my usage of it.

See https://phoenix.apache.org/Phoenix-in-15-minutes-or-less.html. You van use an SQL file. In addition you can use Hue.

Never tried the following for Windows, but it is possible. See https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-connect-a-Windows-JDBC-client-to-Cluster-enabled-with/ta-p/247787

Comment: Note that my queries are often 100 lines long or more so working from the command line is challenging.

Comment: And...I need a Windows client

Comment: Cheers and success.